# EWS .FindItems() method is returning an InternalServerError

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In PowerShell, I'm attempting to bind to a folder in the archive mailbox and run the `.FindItems()` method.  Relevant code samples are below

```
$ItemView    = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView]::new(500)
$SearchQuery = 'From:"V-Mail@MyDomain.com" AND HasAttachment:true AND Subject:"New vmail from"'

Do {
    # Get a page:
    Try {
        $ItemCol = $Service.FindItems( $Inbox.Id, $SearchQuery, $ItemView )
        # $ItemCol = $Service.FindItems( $Inbox.Id, $ItemView )
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Error occured running .FindItems()"
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red  $Error[0].Message
        Throw
    }

    $Items += $ItemCol
    # ^ Avoid +=, change  to simply collect output... 
    
    $ItemView.Offset += $ItemCol.Items.Count
    $Page++
}While( $ItemCol.MoreAvailable -eq $true )
```

This returns an error:

```
Exception calling "FindItems" with "3" argument(s): "Exchange Web Services are not currently available for this request because none of the Client Access Servers in the destination site could process the request."
```

I've managed to isolate EWS log entries on one of the Exchange servers, a segment of which is below:

```
...ErrorTimeoutExpiredException: The search operation could not be completed within the allotted time limit. Please try to narrow down your scope to reduce the result set.
```

There are other mentions of InternalServerError and the HTTP return code is 500.  However, I don't think this is a throttling issue, EWS portions of the throttling policy are below:

```
EwsCostThreshold                      : 50
EwsMaxConcurrency                     : Unlimited
EwsMaxBurst                           : 300000
EwsRechargeRate                       : Unlimited
EwsCutoffBalance                      : Unlimited
EwsMaxSubscriptions                   : 5000
DiscoveryMaxPreviewSearchMailboxes    : 5000
DiscoveryPreviewSearchResultsPageSize : 200
```

It is true that if I leave out the search query, getting all items it works, albeit much slower.   The only change I'm aware of is that we upgraded to Exchange 2019 CU 12.

I'm not sure if it's related, but the folders generating the error "seem" to have over 100,000 items.  That said, this exact technique was used without issue in a previous program.  And, I'm able to confirm the excessive item counts were present at the time.

The code works fine when run against a folder in the primary mailbox, although that folder had significantly less than 100K items.

In Outlook, the same query works fine in both the primary and archive mailboxes.

So, I'm stumped. How can I troubleshoot this further?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the X-AnchorMailbox header as this will help route your request to the correct server/site. If you don't use it the requests get proxied and these type of timeout issue are common eg

```
$service.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", "mailboxtoaccess@domain.com")
```

Comment: Glen, Thanks so much. Not just for this but for all your work!  It's really an honor to be talking with you. I will give this a shot, but quick question, is the "anchor mailbox" the one running the security context or the target mailbox? This is running as delegated, not the user and not impersonation.

Comment: After adding the above using the target mailbox I got a different error: Exception calling "FindItems" with "3" argument(s): "The search operation could not be completed within the allotted time limit. Please try to narrow down your scope to reduce the result set."  This seems similar to what I saw in the EWS logs, but this is a pretty narrow search already in the test case it only returns ~70 items, and again it was working before...

Comment: Do other AQS queries work ? could be its a problem with the search indexing they change the search architecture on 2019 (which should improve performance) could be its just a bad index.

Comment: I've tried multiple queries without success.  I also moved the mailbox which should rebuild the index.  At least that's what MS said. Unlike older versions the index is stored in the mailbox so I don't see why it would.  It was working before, I think the only change was CU12 getting installed.  I guess I'll have to open a case with MS. More to follow.  Thanks.

Comment: Note: I also tried doubling the timeout, but that just made it take longer to fail the same way.

Comment: would you happen to have any insights on how to escalate this through MS Support?

Comment: If you have an MS account or partner manager that tends to be the best way to get something escalated. Its never easy though